# replacing part of regex matches

Tags: vim, vi

I have several functions that start with `get_` in my code:
   `get_num(...)` , `get_str(...)`

I want to change them to `get_*_struct(...)`.

Can I somehow match the `get_*` regex and then replace according to the pattern so that:

`get_num(...)` becomes `get_num_struct(...)`,
`get_str(...)` becomes `get_str_struct(...)`

Can you also explain some logic behind it, because the theoretical regex aren't like the ones used in `UNIX` (or `vi`, are they different?) and I'm always struggling to figure them out.

This has to be done in the `vi` editor as this is main work tool.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transform `get_num(...)` to `get_num_struct(...)`, you need to capture the correct text in the input.  And, you can't put the parentheses in the regular expression because you may need to match pointers to functions too, as in `&get_distance`, and uses in comments.  However, and this depends partially on the fact that you are using vim and partially on how you need to keep the entire input together, I have checked that this works:

```
%s/get_\w\+/&_struct/g
```

On every line, find every expression starting with get_ and continuing with at least one letter, number, or underscore, and replace it with the entire matched string followed by _struct.

Darn it; I shouldn't answer these things on spec.  Note that other regex engines might use \& instead of &.  This depends on having magic set, which is default in vim.

Comment: Whoops.  I'm mixing up regular expression languages.  I'll fix this in a moment.

Comment: I see that it works based on a quick check. I have already +1ed your answer. I leave it to the OP to see if it meets his needs. Cheers.

Comment: I'm too arrogant sometimes.  I do wonder about the OP's motivation.  It seems a bit like the unnecessary type of (reverse) Polish notation.

Comment: All's well that ends well :-) Questions tagged `vi` don't get enough love. Adios amigos.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternate way to do it:

```
%s/get_\(\w*\)(/get_\1_struct(/g
```

What this does:

- `\w` matches to any "word character"; `\w*` matches 0 or more word characters.
- `\(...\)` tells vim to remember whatever matches `...`. So, `\(w*\)` means "match any number of word characters, and remember what you matched.  You can then access it in the replacement with `\1` (or `\2` for the second, etc.)
- So, the overall pattern `get_\(\w*\)(` looks for `get_`, followed by any number of word chars, followed by `(`.
- The replacement then just does exactly what you want.

(Sorry if that was too verbose - not sure how comfortable you are with vim regex.)

Comment: excelleny explanation! much appreciated!